# TIKZ How to capture a particular chain in an argument

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, arguments

I've crated a macro that draws different kinds of 3D coordinates (here: sistemaTd & sistemaT2). 
When I use the included system in tikz, the legend of axis Y lies in a bad position.

I have used `\eixo` hundred times in various files, so I want to find a way without  changes in its number of arguments

I think I need something like this in the definition of `\eixo`:

`IF #2 contains the chain "sistema" DO pos="below" ELSE pos="right" ENDIF`

this is the example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\tikzset{sistemaTd/.style={y={(1 cm,0 cm)},z={(0 cm, 1 cm)},x={(-0.5 cm, -0.5 cm)}}}
\tikzset{sistemaTe/.style={x={(0 cm,1 cm)},y={(1 cm, 0 cm)},z={(-0.5 cm, -0.5 cm)}}}
%eixo{dim}{color, etc} Ejemplo: \texttt{eixo}{black!80,sistemaTd,-latex...}
\newcommand{\eixo}[2]{
    \begin{scope}[->,#2]
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (#1,0,0) node[right]{$X$};
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,#1,0) node[below]{$Y$}; %node[below]{$Y$}
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,#1) node[right]{$Z$};
    \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \eixo{3}{gray,sistemaTd}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=5.5cm]
            \eixo{3}{gray,sistemaTe}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=11cm]
            \eixo{3}{gray} %note the legend of Y axis
        \end{scope}     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I use `listofitems` to search `#2` for the string-separator `sistema`.  If it finds it (as evidenced by a list length > 1), it uses the `below` specifier, else it uses `right`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen,listofitems}
\tikzset{sistemaTd/.style={y={(1 cm,0 cm)},z={(0 cm, 1 cm)},x={(-0.5 cm, -0.5 cm)}}}
\tikzset{sistemaTe/.style={x={(0 cm,1 cm)},y={(1 cm, 0 cm)},z={(-0.5 cm, -0.5 cm)}}}
%eixo{dim}{color, etc} Ejemplo: \texttt{eixo}{black!80,sistemaTd,-latex...}
\newcommand{\eixo}[2]{
    \begin{scope}[->,#2]
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (#1,0,0) node[right]{$X$};
  \setsepchar{sistema}%
  \readlist\argtwo{#2}%
  \ifnum\listlen\argtwo[]>1\relax
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,#1,0) node[below]{$Y$};
  \else
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,#1,0) node[right]{$Y$};
  \fi
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,#1) node[right]{$Z$};
    \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \eixo{3}{gray,sistemaTd}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=5.5cm]
            \eixo{3}{gray,sistemaTe}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=11cm]
            \eixo{3}{gray} %note the legend of Y axis
        \end{scope}     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version that also adjusts the X label location, if I understand the issue properly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen,listofitems}
\tikzset{sistemaTd/.style={y={(1 cm,0 cm)},z={(0 cm, 1 cm)},x={(-0.5 cm, -0.5 cm)}}}
\tikzset{sistemaTe/.style={x={(0 cm,1 cm)},y={(1 cm, 0 cm)},z={(-0.5 cm, -0.5 cm)}}}
%eixo{dim}{color, etc} Ejemplo: \texttt{eixo}{black!80,sistemaTd,-latex...}
\newcommand{\eixo}[2]{
    \begin{scope}[->,#2]
  \setsepchar{sistema}%
  \readlist\argtwo{#2}%
  \ifnum\listlen\argtwo[]>1\relax
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (#1,0,0) node[right]{$X$};
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,#1,0) node[below]{$Y$}; 
  \else
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (#1,0,0) node[below]{$X$};
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,#1,0) node[right]{$Y$};
  \fi
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,#1) node[right]{$Z$};
    \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \eixo{3}{gray,sistemaTd}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=5.5cm]
            \eixo{3}{gray,sistemaTe}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=11cm]
            \eixo{3}{gray} %note the legend of Y axis
        \end{scope}     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check (with `calc`) on the spot if the axis is more horizontal or vertical and attach the label depending on that information. That way this will continue to work if you add more coordinate systems and/or change their definition.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{sistemaTd/.style={y={(1 cm,0 cm)},z={(0 cm, 1 cm)},x={(-0.5 cm, -0.5 cm)}}}
\tikzset{sistemaTe/.style={x={(0 cm,1 cm)},y={(1 cm, 0 cm)},z={(-0.5 cm, -0.5 cm)}}}
%eixo{dim}{color, etc} Ejemplo: \texttt{eixo}{black!80,sistemaTd,-latex...}
\newcommand{\eixo}[2]{
    \begin{scope}[->,#2]
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (#1,0,0) 
        let \p1=($(#1,0,0)-(0,0,0)$),\n1={abs(sin(atan2(\y1,\x1))))} in
        \ifdim\n1<0.4pt [below] \else [right] \fi node  {$X$};
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,#1,0) let \p1=($(0,#1,0)-(0,0,0)$),\n1={abs(sin(atan2(\y1,\x1))))} in
        \ifdim\n1<0.4pt [below] \else [right] \fi node {$Y$}; 
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,#1) let \p1=($(0,0,#1)-(0,0,0)$),\n1={abs(sin(atan2(\y1,\x1))))} in
        \ifdim\n1<0.4pt [below] \else [right] \fi node{$Z$};
    \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \eixo{3}{gray,sistemaTd}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=5.5cm]
            \eixo{3}{gray,sistemaTe}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=11cm]
            \eixo{3}{gray} %note the legend of Y axis
        \end{scope}     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Finnaly I understood your code. It is perfect!